# How to get viewhelper f:widget.autocomplete working in TYPO3 8.7

Tags: autocomplete, typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

I want to use the viewhelper f:widget.autocomplete to implement an autocomplete feature for a search in a little extension in TYPO3 8.7.

The Documentation for TYPO3 8.7. says nothing about it: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-extbasefluid/8.7/en-us/Fluid/ViewHelper/Widget/Autocomplete.html

I tried it as discribed in the Documentation for TYPO3 9.5. https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Widget/Autocomplete.html

I have included the JS- and CSS-Assets and use the viewhelper in the filter-form of my extension:

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="pluginname[search]" />
<f:widget.autocomplete for="search" objects="{myobject}" searchProperty="name" />
```

This integrates a JS-Snippet from sysext/fluid and makes an ajax call, if I put something in the text field.:
http://host/index.php?id=1&type=7076&fluid-widget-id=305d544b2a96a8e5a73db7e93c083586&action=autocomplete&term=myterm

But the response to this call contents the hole page and not only the result of a datatabase query according to my searchterm.

**Now my question**:

What have I to do, to get the autocomplete feature working?

Do I need an extra autocomplete action in my controller?

Or ist there an extra setup for the pageType needed?

Currently the pageType 7076 is configured by the Fluid-Sysextension:

```
fluidAjaxWidgetResponse = PAGE
fluidAjaxWidgetResponse {
     # todo: make page type configurable
    typeNum = 7076
    headerData >
    config {
        no_cache = 1
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        additionalHeaders.10.header = Content-Type: text/plain
        additionalHeaders.10.replace = 1
        debug = 0
    }
    10 = USER_INT
    10 {
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Widget\Bootstrap->run
    }
}

config.tx_extbase {
    mvc {
        requestHandlers {
            TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Widget\WidgetRequestHandler = TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Widget\WidgetRequestHandler
        }
    }
}
```